# django forms for adding new elements

Tags: python, django

I've got in views.py code for my view to add new docs to database:

```
def doc_creation(request):
    # add_form = forms.DocAddForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        add_form = forms.DocAddForm(data=request.POST)

        if add_form.is_valid():
            new_doc = add_form.save(commit=False)
            rnd_nip=TestClass()
            new_doc.doc_client_nip = rnd_nip.random_client_nip()
            new_doc.added_by_2 = request.user

            new_doc.save()

        else:
            add_form = forms.DocAddForm()

    else:
        add_form = forms.DocAddForm()
    return render(request,'doc_new_2.html',{'add_form':add_form})
```

my model code is:

```
class Doc(models.Model):

    doc_client_nip = models.CharField(blank=False,null=False,max_length=100,validators=[MinLengthValidator(10)],primary_key=True)
    doc_application_id = models.CharField(blank=False,null=True,max_length=100,validators=[MinLengthValidator(17)])
    added_by_2 = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

TestClass() with its method random_client_nip() is used to generate random value of this field

The problem is every time when I try to submit new record nothing is added to database
page is reloaded to empty form but I don't receive any error.

What is going on? Is the field added_by_2 problem?

Comment: Are you able to save the new doc from the admin page?

Comment: yes, there's no problem

Comment: And the form is forms.modelform.